# Flatten IQueryable from IQueryable<IGrouping<int, object>> to IQueryable<object>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a problem converting an `IQueryable<IGrouping<int, object>>` to `IQueryable<object>`.

The object is an class with a property of `int Index`.
The `IGrouping's` Key is that index.
I want to to get a merged `IQueryable<object>` where the only the lowest index is considered.

E.g.
Several groupings with

- `IGrouping<3, object>`
- `IGrouping<4, object>`
- `IGrouping<4, object>`
- `IGrouping<5, object>`
- `IGrouping<6, object>`
- `IGrouping<3, object>`
- `IGrouping<3, object>`

The outcome should be a `IQueryable<object>` where only the objects with index **3** are inside.

P.S I need an `IQueryable` to perform DateTime DbFunctions on it. So hopefully this can be done with one SQL query.

Comment: And how did you end up with multiple `IGrouping`s with the same key?

Comment: Your question is unclear and broad. Unclear: it would help to see the `IQueryable` source of the groupings otherwise it can't be judged whether it can be continued as `IQueryable` at all. Broad: you don't show your own efforts so it's hard to see where specifically you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i finally found a suitable solution.
The problem with previous answers was always the `First()` call.

```
list.Where(SomeFilterExpression)
    .GroupBy(e => e.Index)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Take(1)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(e => e))
    .Where(SomeAdditionalFilterExpression)
    .ToList()
```

This code (especially the `Take()` helped me to solve my problem using only **one** SQL query)
Anyhow thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 3):

To flatten the groups as described, you need to:

1. Sort objects within each group by Index
2. Get the first top object from each group

This code sample demonstrates the `LINQ` query:

```
IQueryable<MyObject> objects = new[]
{
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 3, Index = 31, OtherProperty = "Group 3 / Index 31" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 3, Index = 32, OtherProperty = "Group 3 / Index 32" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 3, Index = 32, OtherProperty = "Group 3 / Index 32" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 4, Index = 43, OtherProperty = "Group 4 / Index 43" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 4, Index = 42, OtherProperty = "Group 4 / Index 42" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 4, Index = 45, OtherProperty = "Group 4 / Index 45" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 4, Index = 46, OtherProperty = "Group 4 / Index 46" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 5, Index = 51, OtherProperty = "Group 5 / Index 51" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 5, Index = 54, OtherProperty = "Group 5 / Index 54" },
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 6, Index = 67, OtherProperty = "Group 6 / Index 67" },
    // ...                                                                    
    new MyObject{ GroupId = 6, Index = 63, OtherProperty = "Group 6 / Index 63" }
}.AsQueryable();

IQueryable<IGrouping<int, MyObject>> groups = objects.GroupBy(o => o.GroupId);

IQueryable<MyObject> outcome = groups.Select(grouping => grouping.OrderBy(g => g.Index).First());

List<MyObject> outcomeList = outcome.ToList();

// outcomeList contains: 
// new MyObject{ GroupId = 3, Index = 31, OtherProperty = "Group 3 / Index 31" };
// new MyObject{ GroupId = 4, Index = 42, OtherProperty = "Group 4 / Index 42" };
// new MyObject{ GroupId = 5, Index = 51, OtherProperty = "Group 5 / Index 51" };
// new MyObject{ GroupId = 6, Index = 63, OtherProperty = "Group 6 / Index 63" };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort your groups with `OrderBy` and then take a first group with `FirstOrDefault`

```
var firstGroup = list.GroupBy(x => x.Index)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .AsQueryable();
```

Please see an [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zPQoHq)

Comment: i work with linq-to-sql and need an IQueryable not an IEnumerable

Comment: @Muarl please see my edit. I've tested it with linqPad and my database. It produces two sql queries: first to get minimal key, second to fetch all records with that key

Comment: Unfortunately no, the problem here is the FirstOrDefault call, additionally I guess it's possible to achieve this with 1 sql query

Answer (score 0):

> SelectMany

will flatten out, then you can again sort and get order by result either first or last. But for Items in Groups to return single result set SelectMany is there